# How can we access specific Google Analytics account data using API and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-sdk

We are developing an app that intended to access website data of other websites owners who are registered on our app.

What we want that user will login into their gmail account and provide our app access to their google analytics account for their website.

We need complete implementation using c# of google analytics API where we can ask user to give our app access. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So you need a complete implementation, without providing any attempts you have tried thus far? Here I refer you to the Embed API guide -
 also see Google's Reporting API Guide https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/

Comment: ColinM How would you concluded that we haven't attempted anything. We have trying this past from 2 months but didn't get success. That doesn't means we never tried.

Comment: Because there is no code included in your question of what you have actually tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Google Analytics Reporting API. There is quick start guide is available for the Java, Python and PHP. I have created custom reports in PHP.

Use this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/

Here you can use REST APIs in your C# application:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/basics